# Connect to meteor mongo from local docker image on Mac

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker

`meteor mongo -U` shows me `mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor` as the connection string. I understand that the docker image will try to connect to itself and fail. I tried substituting 127.0.0.1 for any IP address I could find when running `ifconfig` with the same result:

```
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001' }
```

Not sure what else I can try to resolve this. Any pointers will be appreciated.

More Information:
`mongo 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor` works from a different shell window. But no other IP addresses work: `mongo 10.0.0.96:3001/meteor`:

```
2015-11-16T10:16:14.089-0500 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 10.0.0.96:3001, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-11-16T10:16:14.091-0500 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 10.0.0.96:3001 (10.0.0.96), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

======================
Additional set up information ====================

create a basic meteor app: `meteor create app` `cd app` `meteor` 
. In another terminal in the same folder `app` run `meteor mongo -U` to get connection string: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor`. Now in a different folder create a node app that wants to connect to a mongo db: `mkdir worker`, `cd worker`, `npm install mongodb`, create worker.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor", function(err, db) {

    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    }

});
```

and finally run in docker:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/worker -w /worker iron/images:node-4.1 sh -c "node worker.js"
```

docker IP address is 192.168.99.100
One of the IP addresses I have listed from ifconfig is

```
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

I plug it in, run the docker command and get this:

```
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.1:3001]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.1:3001' }
```

Comment: can you lay out the setup a bit more: where is meteor running (inside the docker container or outside?), what is the IP of the docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So assuming here that you are running your meteor app in your local Mac and then your docker container for your node app is running in a `docker-machine`. Probably VirtualBox? if you are using the default docker-machine on MacOS (boot2docker)

The problem is that your container that runs in a VM on your MacOS machine cannot necessarily talk to the same network as the one where your MacOS machine actually is (using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`)

For example from my Mac:

```
$ ifconfig
...
vboxnet0: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
vboxnet1: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01
vboxnet2: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02
inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
vboxnet3: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:03
...
```

You see that the VirtualBox net `vboxnet2` is the `192.168.99.x` range. If you ssh into your `docker-machine`

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.8.1, build master : 7f12e95 - Thu Aug 13 03:24:56 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79
docker@default:~$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:2C:33:C7:80
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:2cff:fe33:c780/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:62290 (60.8 KiB)  TX bytes:2561234 (2.4 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:CC:FD:18
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecc:fd18/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:482311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:209033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:401054787 (382.4 MiB)  TX bytes:12923400 (12.3 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:E6:C7:20
          inet addr:192.168.99.100  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:c720/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3259250 (3.1 MiB)  TX bytes:10663711 (10.1 MiB)
```

You see that your container net is `172.17.x.x`. So any container will belong to that network and it will not necessarily be able to route to another using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Ok so there's a way you can access the mongodb on your host machine (MacOS) The docker container can see it through the `vboxnet2` ip address `192.168.99.1` but the catch here is that mongodb has to bind to `0.0.0.0` (any IP) instead of `127.0.0.1`. So if you look at the default mongodb running with `meteor` on your Mac.

```
 $ ps -Af | grep mongo
  503 75294 73105   0  6:08PM ttys005    0:00.00 grep mongo
  503 74375 74356   0  5:55PM ttys006    0:02.17 /Users/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1sd3e7j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --port 3001 --dbpath /Users/username/work/meteor/app/.meteor/local/db --oplogSize 8 --replSet meteor
```

you see that it's bound to IP `127.0.0.1` so when you try from your container:

```
user@b4d40a25f67d:/worker#:/worker# telnet 192.168.99.1 3001
```

you get no response.

The hack here is to just bind to `0.0.0.0` (not recommended for production):

```
~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.9/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/runners/run-mongo.js


-   '--bind_ip', '127.0.0.1', '--smallfiles', '--port', port, '--dbpath', dbPath,
+   '--bind_ip', '0.0.0.0', '--smallfiles', '--port', port, '--dbpath', dbPath,
```

Then voilá:

```
user@b4d40a25f67d:/worker# telnet 192.168.99.1 3001
Trying 192.168.99.1...
Connected to 192.168.99.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Then, you need to modify this line in your worker.js

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://192.168.99.1:3001/meteor", function(err, db) {
```

And I'm happy to say that it works! :

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/worker -w /worker iron/images:node-4.1 sh -c 'node worker.js'
Connected correctly to server
```

Comment: Yes! It didn't work initially for me because I used the exact path you mentioned for run-mongo.js file. I found that I have version 1.1.10 installed under meteor-tool, followed the rest of the path, updated the file and it worked. Thank you!